# How can I send a csv file to d3.js in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, csv, d3.js

I am currently using Django+D3.js. 
And the template(**viewCSV.html**) contain a js function which need a csv file:

```
d3.text("{{ file }}", function(data) {
            var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(data);

            var container = d3.select("body")
                .append("table")

                .selectAll("tr")
                    .data(parsedCSV).enter()
                    .append("tr")

                .selectAll("td")
                    .data(function(d) { return d; }).enter()
                    .append("td")
                    .text(function(d) { return d; });
        });
```

Without using Django, the function should be `d3.text("train.csv", function(data) {...}`

Now I write following codes in my **views.py**

```
def viewCSV(request):
    fp = open('train.csv', 'rb')
    data = fp.read()
    variables = RequestContext('viewCSV.html', {'file': data})
    t = get_template('viewCSV.html')
    output = t.render(variables)
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

By the way, the viewCSV.html and train.csv are in the same folder under the Django project.

When I run the server, and visit the url, I got

> AttributeError at /viewCSV/
>   'str' object has no attribute 'META'

I just want let the js read the csv file. 
I don't know how to implement it.
Can any one help me with this question?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to a RequestContext is the request, not the template name.

There's no need for all this long-winded stuff though: the last four lines of your function could just be replaced with:

```
return render(request, 'viewCSV.html', {'file': data})
```

where `render` is imported from `django.shortcuts`.

Comment: But doesn't [d3.text](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/blob/master/README.md#text) expect an URL as input?

Answer (score 0):

You want to insert the file name into your template, not the contents of the file.  It looks like you're reading the data into your view function and then inserting the data into your template.  Just insert the file name instead, and let `d3.text` do it's thing (you could also use `d3.csv`, which is what I would use).

ie:

```
def viewCSV(request):
    variables = RequestContext(request, {'file': 'train.csv'})
    t = get_template('viewCSV.html')
    output = t.render(variables)
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

and doing it like @Daniel Roseman (which is how I'd do it, BTW)

```
def viewCSV(request):
    return render(request, 'viewCSV.html', {'file': 'train.csv'})
```